# Azure AD does not sends claims info in Id or Access tokens

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm trying to connect Azure ActiveDirectory with Keycloak using `OpenID Connect v1.0` protocol.

I connected Keycloak and I can login with azure account in Keycloak, but I can't pass any optional claims to my `id` or `access tokens`. They have only standard fields. On the frontend side I'm checking the `/token` path after login.

In my Manifest i see optional claims in both tokens.
I gave all possible accesses to claims on security tab but all without success.

Can you please give me a tipp, how can i solve this? What should i look/check?
I need to transfer roles/groups from azure account to my Keycloak and map them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For optional claims or attributes to be present in Id token or access token ,

Check the added optional claims  in Azure AD for the application.

[image]

In the keycloak , create the mappers to reflect in Id token or access token.

- In the realm in keycloak , go to Clients in the dashboard and select your client.
- Navigate to 'Mappers' label  and click 'Create'.

[image]

Then for example mapper type can be of 'User Attribute' or Attributr importer for different Identity provider.

If that is selected , then fill the attribute name that user actually has when authenticates and select the appropriate option , if it is to be included  in  any of ID token, access token and userinfo.

[image]

---

In case of mapping from another IDP i.e; here  **Azure AD**

[image]

refer this [sample for okta](https://ultimatesecurity.pro/post/okta-update-user/)

**For example If upn is selected for optional claim in AzureAD:**

[image]

From **`Identiy Providers`** blade , select **`mappers`** and use ***`attribute importer`*** for mapper type.

[image]
**References:**

1. [Server Administration Guide -protocol mappers (keycloak.org)](https://Server%20Administration%20Guide%20(keycloak.org))
2. [azure-ad-as-oidc-identity-provider-in-keycloak | | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67799490/azure-ad-as-oidc-identity-provider-in-keycloak-but-a-random-uuid-is-added-as-id)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed instructions. I can already see that I have not yet tried one thing, or did it wrong. I'll try it on Monday and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Your answer give me one more idea. I checked it and found my error. The problem was not with Azure Token but with "client scopes" on Keycloak side. I didn't know, that i should configure Keycloak mapping too. Thanks! I get Optional Azure Claims in my keycloak token. I should do double mapping. Azure -> Keycloak (Attributes/Roles) -> Keycloak token.

Comment: @JDev - I'm trying to do the same thing - can you give more details?

Comment: @JackBeNimble Unfortunately no. I already left this company and forgot about it. But what I can say for sure is that mapping needs to be configured in the provider and then also in the settings of the token creation(client) itself, which will be returned to the user.
That is, it is not enough to simply configure the IdentityProvider. We still need to make some minor changes to the Keycloak client itself. This was precisely my big misunderstanding, which is why attributes are not forwarded from Azure. Azure works as it should, you need to configure Keycloak correctly.