# How to get Keycloak identity broker to display claims in ID token from Entra ID / Azure identity Provider

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, claims-based-identity, microsoft-entra-id, oidc-identity-brokering

I'm trying to retrieve some claims (roles, groups, upn) from an ID token using Keycloak as an identity provider for an OIDC app configured on Entra ID.

Using Postman, I can retrieve the ID token directly from Entra ID and the claims are there. So it's just a question of configuring Keycloak to correctly map the claims.

I've tried following [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74796170/azure-ad-does-not-sends-claims-info-in-id-or-access-tokens), but with no luck. I've tried both the mapping described and even adding a upn client scope. Ideally, I'm trying to get the roles.

Can someone provide some insight on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `upn` field as written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/optional-claims-reference#v20-specific-optional-claims-set) it's required the scope `profile`.
Open the advanced settings, in the keycloak section "identity provider" and make sure you've added `openid profile` in the list of scopes. By default it's empty that means only `openid`